# MS Access 2010 Triggers/data macros

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am developing a database to do a annual inventory count with 32 tables in it, 33 including the Master.

We currently have 4000 SKU's so the master table needed to be broken down into smaller tables so I can hand out a realistic amount of work to my counters.

What I am trying to achive is when my counters enter data in the smaller tables using the UI it would automatically populate the fields in the master table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Comment: We'll need more information than what you provided to answer this. Please edit for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, there is no way to apply a trigger to a table. What you can do is create a form that implements a grid. Have an After-Update event fire that does what you need. You can make the form look like a table by using the datasheet view.

Comment: Access 2010 includes a new feature related to triggers and called data macros: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx

Comment: Thanks Remou...this is an awesome addition to the application.

Comment: You should move this to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you can create a data macro* to update a table from an update on another, why would you want to do it in this case? You can either include the quantity field in the sub table and validate the data against the main table before running an update query, or the sub table (note, table, the employee ID will be sufficient to divide the data) could consist only of an employee id and an SKU, the sub table can then be joined to the main table by SKU and all updates use the quantity field from the main table:

```
SELECT Mytable1.SKU, MyTable.Quantity 
FROM MyTable1
INNER JOIN MyTable 
ON MyTable1.SKU = MyTable.SKU
WHERE EmployeeID = [Enter ID: ]
```

---

*[Data Macro](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx)

[image: data macro]